# One select sum, the same one minus another sum inside a single query

Tags: sql, select, sum

I've got these three tables:

- account: id(pk), value, ug(fk), flag
- justify: id(pk), value, account_id(fk)
- client: id(pk), ug(fk)

I have these two selects:

```
select sum(account.value)
  from account, client
 where client.ug_id = account.ug and flag = 1

select sum(justify.value)
  from justify, client, account
 where client.ug_id = account.ug
   and flag = 1 and justify.account_id = account.id
```

What I'm trying to do is put them together in a single query, like this:

```
select
1,
1-2,
account.ug
from account
group by account.ug
```

but I can't find a way to do it; any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add better info about the tables and the data on them, it would help a bit.

Also, if you use a join instead of a select from various tables the query will perform better thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  There shouldn't be any performance difference between the lit of tables in the FROM clause and a list of JOINs, but the latter is generally easier to understand.  There are no GROUP BY clauses; is that what you really wanted -- a single number from each query?  Your combined query includes GROUP BY, so it is not clear that it is more than remotely related to the first two.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really told us much about your schema. But (taking a stab at things) ...

First, you should be using ANSI/ISO joins, not old-school joins. ANSI/ISO joins are much easier to read. Once you do that, you're going to want to use *derived table*, which are subqueries in the `from` clause that act as a virtual view. Then, something like this ought to do you:

```
select ug    = account.ug , -- guaranteed to be present ,
       total = coalesce( total.value   , 0 ) ,
       delta = coalesce( total.value   , 0 ) ,
             - coalesce( justify.value , 0 )
from      ( select distinct -- we do select distinct here
                   ug       -- to guarantee at least one row for every UG
            from account    -- some account UGs might be missing client rows
          ) account         -- and/or some might be missing justify rows.
left join ( select ug    = account.ug ,
                   value = sum(account.value)
            from account
            join client  on client.ug_id = account.ug
            where flag = 1
            group by account.ug
          ) total on total.ug = account.ug
left join ( select ug    = account.ug ,
                   value = sum(justify.value)
            from account
            join justify on justify.account_id = account.id
            join client  on client.ug_id       = account.ug
            where flag = 1
            group by account.ug
          ) justify on justify.ug = account.ug
```

Comment: Which DBMS uses the 'alias = real-value' notation?  SQL standard would be 'real-value AS alias'.  It's not wrong, but it is unusual.

Comment: SQL Server, DB2, etc. That convention has been around since, oh, DB2 Release 1. Oracle doesn't support it, but Oracle is about the least standard RDBMS out there. The problem with AS is that in complex SELECTS with a lot of derived columns and complex expressions in the select-list, the name of the derived column names get lots in the shuffle. Using name=expression makes the select much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

We really shouldn't have to do any guesswork on your question, but it seems guesswork is necessary.

I think your three tables are:

1. **Account** — id (PK), value, ug (FK references Client), flag
2. **Client** — ug (PK)
3. **Justify** — value, account_id (PK, also FK references Account)

I assume that there are no accounts without a client, and no justify entries without an account (so the PK and FK constraints are all enforced by the DBMS).  This means that it is not necessary to select from the Client table.

If you want Clients who don't necessarily have any accounts listed too, you would probably be best off with a separate query, but it could be done if necessary — you would have to clarify your question, and use an extra level of outer join, and worry about nulls versus zeros, etc.

And it appears that the required output is:

- For each Client, list the client identifier (`ug`), the sum of the values of their accounts in the Accounts table (account.value), and also the value of their accounts minus the sum of the values in the Justify table.  It is not clear whether there will always be values in the Justify table for every account.

However, we can attempt to provide the information by building the queries piecemeal.

#### Aggregate values of accounts for a particular user

```
SELECT a.ug, SUM(a.value) AS ac_value
  FROM Account AS a
 WHERE a.flag = 1
 GROUP BY a.ug
```

#### Aggregate values of Justify for a particular user

```
SELECT a.ug, SUM(j.value) AS ju_value
  FROM Account AS a
  JOIN Justify AS j ON j.account_id = a.id
 WHERE a.flag = 1
 GROUP BY a.ug
```

#### Join of previous two result tables

```
SELECT b.ug, b.ac_value, b.ac_value - NVL(d.ju_value, 0) AS delta
  FROM (SELECT a.ug, SUM(a.value) AS ac_value
          FROM Account AS a
         WHERE a.flag = 1
         GROUP BY a.ug
       ) AS b
  LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT a.ug, SUM(j.value) AS ju_value
          FROM Account AS a
          JOIN Justify AS j ON j.account_id = a.id
         WHERE a.flag = 1
         GROUP BY a.ug
       ) AS d ON b.ug = d.ug
```

The use of NVL allows for clients with no entries in the Justify table; the LEFT JOIN is also part of that.